# Passing value from ajax function of one page to ajax function on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to send Rest_ID to another page and using the Rest_ID the ajax on other page is used to fetch data from database.Everything working fine but i am not able to use the value of Rest_ID.

JavaScript Document for fecthing restaurants details on page Restaurant.php

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    loadData();
});

var loadData = function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "../rest_fetch.php"
    }).done(function(data){
       var restaurants = JSON.parse(data);
       for(var i in restaurants){
         $("#ft_Rest_list").append("<center><a href='restmenu.php?restid="+restaurants[i].Rest_ID+"'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success load-more-btn' style='border-color:#333;border-radius:0;''>View Menu</button></a></center></div></div>")
       }
    });
}
```

JavaScript Document for fecthing item details on page menuitem.php using Rest_ID which is passed by restaurant.php button

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    loadData();
});

var loadData = function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "../menuitem_fetch.php",
        data:{"Rest_ID": 201600065},
    }).done(function(data){
       var menuitems = JSON.parse(data);
       for(var i in menuitems){
         $("#ft_menuitems").append("<div class='col-sm-3'><div class='thumbnail'><img src='admin/admin/"+menuitems[i].menu_img+"' alt='RestImage'style='width:200px;height:200px;'><h5><strong>"+menuitems[i].Item_Name+"</strong></h5><a href='checkout.php?itemid="+menuitems[i].Item_No+"'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success buy-btn' style='border-color:#333;background-color:transparent;border-radius:0;color:#333;''>BUY</button></a></div></div>")

       }
    });
}
```

I need help in getting the value of Rest_ID which is send by restaurant.php page and use by ajax function of menuitem.php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use query parameter when you redirect from one page to another.
Let say that when you click some item on restaurant.php you will redirect to

```
menuitem.php?Rest_ID=ID
```

so after on menuitem.php you can get Rest_ID by:

```
var loc = location.search;
loc = loc.split('=')
var Rest_ID = loc[1]
```

and put it to your request:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "../menuitem_fetch.php",
    data:{"Rest_ID": Rest_ID},
})
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.url is not a function,This error is shown when i use your code

Comment: I fixed this error with pure JS - hope it works @AashishKaushik